# Catching any click performed using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, onclick, jquery-events

The noob way to do it I guess would be

```
$('*').click(function(){...});
```

**But is there any way I can catch any type of click, without having to register a listener for every object in the DOM?**

---

Help would be amazing. =)

Answer (score 36):

A `click` event will  by default [bubble up the DOM](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html), so you can just attach a `click` handler to the root, like this:

```
$(document).click(function() {
  //do something
});
```

Unless a handler on an element along the way does an [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) or `return false`, you'll get the click here.

Comment: +1, was just writing this.  This assumes that no other click handlers cancel the bubbling using `event.stopPropagation()`, of course.

Comment: The event.stopPropagation() was very useful to know! Thanks for including this

Comment: @Andy - +1 - Important point, was adding that while you were commenting :)

Answer (score 23):

You can use event delegation on the document to catch all clicks.

jQuery will fill the `target` property of the `event` to retrieve the clicked element.

```
$(document).click(function(event){
  // event.target is the clicked object
});
```

Note that `event.target` will be the deepest element clicked. Ex: if there is a `<span>` in a `<a>`, you will get the `<span>`, not the `<a>`.

If you want to catch any click but want to retrieve a specific element (like a class), you can do:

```
$(document).click(function(event){
  $(event.target).closest(".clickable").each(function(){
    // "this" is your "clickable" clicked
  });
});
```

Unless an event handler on an element along the way does an [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) or `return false`, you'll get the click here.

Comment: Thanks this is an amazing reply, thanks for including information wasn't necessary but VERY useful! If you could also add the "event.stopPropagation()" fact, I would be happy to tick this answer =D

Comment: I believe `.closest()` will only return one parent object, so using `.each()` would be unnecessary.

Comment: @fudgey - That would depend on the usage, for example `$(this).plugin({ option: this.id });` couldn't be chained (`this` would be the wrong element), but lives inside the `.each()` closure nicely.

Comment: @fudgey `.closest()` may actually return an empty jQuery, so using `.each()` is a shortcut to using an `if` to test the existence of the return value

Comment: And if you want to stop the event if the click is on a certain element:   `if ($(event.target).closest('#myElement').length > 0 ) { event.stopPropagation(); }`

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
$('body').click(function(){...});
```

Any click will be on the body, since that is the parent of all visible nodes in the dom.

Comment: looks like in jQuery 3 `.click(function(){...});` is deprecated you need to use `$(document).on('click', 'body', function(){});`

Answer (score 4):

How about just attaching a click to the body?

```
$('body').click(function(e){ ... })
```

The `e.target` should contain what was clicked on

Answer (score 4):

`$('*').click( function() {...} )` will only catch clicks on elements that existed when you made the call to `.click()`. To catch clicks on elements that may be created later you will need to bind to `body` or `document` as others have suggested.

Comment: Thanks for this extra piece of knowledge, very valuable.

Comment: Note that this will bind the click event handler on every element in your DOM which will consume more memory and will require more CPU when the page is running.